# SQL ROW_NUMBER() always return 1 for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this part of a query here:

```
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS 'SortOrder'
    FOR XML PATH(''), Type
)
```

This is for XML. My issue is that `ROW_NUMBER()` always returns 1, how come it's not returning a different number for each row?

FULL Query:

```
Select
(

Select cast ('<'+ V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER + '>' +
  cast(

   (Select


        (
        SELECT CONVERT(date, V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS 'closingDate'
        FOR XML PATH(''), Type
        ),
        (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.ID67,V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END)-1 AS 'DaysOfConstruction'
        FOR XML PATH(''), Type
        ),
        (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS 'DaysToClosing'
        FOR XML PATH(''), Type
        ),
        (
            SELECT
            CASE WHEN COALESCE(V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.IDNOTES2, '') = '' THEN ' ' ELSE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.IDNOTES2 END AS 'notes'
            FOR XML PATH(''), Type
        ),
        (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.ID187,V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.ID187) AS 'ScheduleVariance'
        FOR XML PATH(''), Type
        ),
        (
        SELECT SortOrder FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END)
            AS 'SortOrder') AS SubQuery
FOR XML PATH(''), Type
        )


    for xml path(''))
    as varchar(max)

    )
    + '</'+ V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER + '>'
 as xml)
 )
 from ((homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES 
        ON 
            V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER) 
        INNER JOIN 
            homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES 
        ON 
            (V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER) AND (V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER)) 
        INNER JOIN 
            homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES 
        ON 
            ((V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER) AND (V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER)) 
            AND (V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER)



WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC = 'Ancaster Augusta Ph 4(A) Condos' AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE()
ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Root')
```

Comment: ...where's the `FROM` clause? Without that, you only have one row. You probably want to move this subquery one level up before you apply `FOR XML`. More context is needed to know how to fix this.

Comment: It's a shame you don't provide sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common for analytic functions to be used through a derived table so that the column is produced and then accessed later by a subsequent clauses via the column alias. It is particularly common when needing to use row_number() results in a where clause. e.g.

```
select * from (select *
                  , row_number(partition by X order by Y) as rn
               from table1
               ) as d
where d.rn = 1
```

Here I believe the same logic applies, you want to calculate a sortorder column THEN place the data into an XML result. My guess is you want to partition by job number.

```
FROM (
  SELECT
        *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
                            ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS 'SortOrder'
  FROM homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
                    AND V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
                    AND V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
                    AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
  WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC = 'Ancaster Augusta Ph 4(A) Condos'
        AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE()
  ) AS d
```

and as a full query:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT
              CAST('<' + V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER + '>' +
              CAST((
                    SELECT (
                                 SELECT
                                       CONVERT(date, d.DATE_TO_END) AS 'closingDate'
                                 FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
                           )
                         , (
                                 SELECT
                                       DATEDIFF(dd, d.ID67, V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) - 1 AS 'DaysOfConstruction'
                                 FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
                           )
                         , (
                                 SELECT
                                       DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), d.DATE_TO_END) AS 'DaysToClosing'
                                 FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
                           )
                         , (
                                 SELECT
                                       CASE
                                             WHEN COALESCE(d.IDNOTES2, '') = '' THEN ' '
                                             ELSE d.IDNOTES2
                                       END AS 'notes'
                                 FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
                           )
                         , (
                                 SELECT
                                       DATEDIFF(dd, d.ID187, d.ID187) AS 'ScheduleVariance'
                                 FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
                           )
                         , (
                                 SELECT
                                       SortOrder
                                 FROM (
                                       SELECT
                                             d.SortOrder
                                 ) AS SubQuery
                                 FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
                           )


                    FOR xml PATH ('')
              )
              AS varchar(max)

              )
              + '</' + V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER + '>'
              AS xml)
  )
FROM (
  SELECT
        *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
                            ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS "SortOrder"
  FROM homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
                    AND V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
                    AND V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
                    AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
  WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC = 'Ancaster Augusta Ph 4(A) Condos'
        AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE()
  ) AS d
ORDER BY
      V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END
FOR xml PATH (''), ROOT ('Root')
```

Comment: I get all these errors with your code:`Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'AREA_DESC' was specified multiple times for 'd'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER" could not be bound.`

Comment: I got it down to one error `The column 'AREA_DESC' was specified multiple times for 'd'.`

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the alias changes that I forgot to do (now corrected), Being unable to run the query I can't ensure it is error free even now.

Answer (score 5):

You're putting `ROW_NUMBER()` inside of a scalar subquery with exactly one row:

```
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END)
        AS 'SortOrder')
```

You're probably thinking that the `ORDER BY` clause (which references a column from the outer query) makes any difference to the calculation of `ROW_NUMBER()` here. It doesn't. This subquery returns one row and the only reasonable `ROW_NUMBER` for that row is always `1`.

The solution is to delay conversion of your results to XML for as long as possible and just select your data ordinarily, with the `ROW_NUMBER()` calculation at the top level `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery for your needs. Try something like this:

```
SELECT SortOrder FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END)
            AS 'SortOrder') AS SubQuery
FOR XML PATH(''), Type
```

Edit:
After reviewing full query I can recommend you another solution.

Actualy you will have all query logic inside your subselect and ROW_NUMBER() function will work perfectly. The outside part will cover query in XML.

**P.S. Little bit more explained:**

```
SELECT (
    SELECT CAST('<'+JOB_NUMBER + '>' +  
        CAST((SELECT
            (SELECT closingDate FOR XML PATH(''), Type),
            (SELECT DaysOfConstruction FOR XML PATH(''), Type),
            (SELECT DaysToClosing FOR XML PATH(''), Type),
            (SELECT notes FOR XML PATH(''), Type),
            (SELECT ScheduleVariance FOR XML PATH(''), Type),
            (SELECT SortOrder FOR XML PATH(''), Type)
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    + '</'+ JOB_NUMBER + '>' as xml))
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER,
        CONVERT(date, V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS closingDate,
        DATEDIFF(dd, V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.ID67,V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) - 1 AS DaysOfConstruction,
        DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(),V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS DaysToClosing,
        (CASE WHEN COALESCE(V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.IDNOTES2, '') = '' THEN ' ' ELSE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.IDNOTES2 END) AS notes,
        DATEDIFF(dd, V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.ID187,V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.ID187) AS ScheduleVariance,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END) AS SortOrder
    FROM homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER 
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES ON 
            V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER AND V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
        INNER JOIN homefront.dbo.V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES ON 
                V_CONSTAT_BASE_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER AND V_CONSTAT_PROJ_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER 
                AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER=V_CONSTAT_SCH_DATES.JOB_NUMBER
    WHERE V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.AREA_DESC = 'AnCASTer Augusta Ph 4(A) Condos' AND V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.DATE_TO_END>=GETDATE()) AS SubQuery
ORDER BY closingDate
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Root')
```

Comment: Can you post whole query? I think there is something missing.

Comment: It just seems to me your ROW_NUMBER is working in one row scope.

Comment: Look for changed answer)

Comment: Added more explained example. The main goal is to replace FROM statement with JOINs on your full query without xml paths. Just your select statement withh all your columns and filters. The query above will only create XML from your subquery.

Comment: I get an error with your code `The column 'JOB_NUMBER' was specified multiple times for 'SubQuery'.`

Comment: Just delete it from the last column in subselect. I had edited the query again. Try it again.

Comment: No problem. Can you mark reply as the answer? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for marking another answer as correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113963/discussion-between-andrey-nadezhdin-and-user979331).